# Column Read and Average (BASH)

Tags: bash

so I'm dealing with column averaging problems

I have several columns of number,

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
8 4 5 6 7
9 8 7 6 5
1 9 9 9 2
```

What I want to do is to take an average of each column so that they will yield

```
4 5 5 6 5
```

The summing part is not a problem, I'm able to get the sum of each column. However, somehow I'm having trouble in counting the number of columns (variable $x) 
Here is my code

```
while read line; do
   x = 0
   read -a array <<< "$line"

    for i in "${!array[@]}"
    do
        column[${i}]=$((${column[${i}]}+${array[$i]}))
        ((x++))
    done
done < $TMP

for sum in ${column[@]}
do
    average=`expr $sum / $x`
    remainder=`expr $sum % $x`
    mult=`expr $remainder \* 10`
    fracvalue=`expr $mult / $x`
    echo $x
    echo $average
    echo $sum
    echo $remainder
    echo $mult
    echo $fracvalue
done
```

The last several lines are for my testing purposes, here the $X keeps showing 1 instead of 5. That's why it screws up all the other variable. Does anybody know where's the flaw in this code? Really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -ia sum        # declare array of integers
declare -i lines=0     # declare integer to count lines

# read file to array and sum values
while read -ra array; do
  for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]};i++)); do 
    sum[$i]+=${array[$i]}
  done
  lines+=1
done < file

# print averages
for ((j=0; j<$i;j++)); do            
  echo -n "$((${sum[$j]}/$lines)) "
done
```

Output:

```
4 5 5 6 5
```

Comment: This is actually works! Thank you! Even though it is quite different, I'll try to figure out this code first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line
`x = 0`
should be 
`x=0` and make `((x+1))` as `let "x+=1"` it should work.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, in my code it is already x=0. However, the append still doesn't work. Now it just simply make the x becomes 0 permanently

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your file doesn't have the same number of lines in each column.

```
while read line; do
   read -a array <<< "$line"

    for i in "${!array[@]}"
    do
      column[${i}]=$((${column[${i}]}+${array[$i]}))
      ((x[${i}]++))
    done
done < $TMP

for i in ${!column[@]}
do
    sum=${column[$i]}
    x=${x[${i}]}
    #your calcul
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial issue, aside from a few syntax peculiarities, was the resetting of `x` on each `read` which caused you to lose your line count. Additionally, your array is an *indexed* array, not an *associative* array.

Making the small adjustments and `declare`ing the variables at the beginning (to hint to bash they are integers or arrays), it works as planned. **note:** there is no need for a *here-string* to assign the array, just use regular array syntax. Also note, for indexed arrays, there is no need to dereference the variable within `[ ]`, simply `${array[i]}` is fine.

While the use of `expr` is fine (old, slow, but portable and fine), you could use bash arithmetic syntax for your parameter calculations at the end. (you already have arrays). Finally, you are better served initializing each `column[$i]=0` on the first read loop. You can do that with a simple flag:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i ncols=0
declare -i x=0
declare -a column

while read -r line; do

    array=( $line )
    [ $ncols -eq 0 ] && ncols=${#array[@]}

    for ((i = 0; i < ncols; i++))
    do
        [ $x -eq 0 ] && column[$i]=0
        column[$i]=$(( ${column[i]} + ${array[i]}))
    done

    ((x++))

done < "$1"

for sum in ${column[@]}
do
    average=`expr $sum / $x`
    remainder=`expr $sum % $x`
    mult=`expr $remainder \* 10`
    fracvalue=`expr $mult / $x`
    echo $x
    echo $average
    echo $sum
    echo $remainder
    echo $mult
    echo $fracvalue
done

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash colavg.sh dat/colavg.txt
5
4
21
1
10
2
5
5
26
1
10
2
5
5
28
3
30
6
5
6
30
0
0
0
5
5
25
0
0
0
```